# Email application not displaying message bodies

Tags: email, imap, stock-email-app, yahoo-mail

Below is a picture of the problem one of my users is having on their VZW Motorola Droid RAZR running ICS.  The picture (click to enlarge) is a screenshot of the default email application configured to sync Yahoo Mail over IMAP. The white border in the bottom of the picture is where emails are normally displayed.  There does not seem to be any determinant in which emails present this problem.  Does any one know why this issue might present, and how to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the email body a giant image, perhaps? I wouldn't be entirely surprised if there's a setting or something that's blocking image loading by default since that's fairly common nowadays.

Comment: No, there are text only emails that display this problem as well.    Examples are emails from friends and family members (might have a graphic signature but that is all)

Comment: A few things to try: 1) clear the cache of the mail app; 2) check logcat for errors

Comment: I forgot to mention I did clear the cache in attempt to fix the problem.   I'm not sure what to look for with logcat, is there something specific maybe?